# G722 in gstreamer is not available or its need to be activated? How do i do that?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, video, media

Gstreamer how to use G.722 enc and dec? Is this not available or missing in there implementation?

```
$ gst-inspect | grep ffmpeg
ffmpeg:  ffaudioresample: FFMPEG Audio resampling element
ffmpeg:  ffdeinterlace: FFMPEG Deinterlace element
ffmpeg:  ffmux_yuv4mpegpipe: FFmpeg YUV4MPEG pipe format muxer (not recommended, use y4menc instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_webm: FFmpeg WebM file format muxer (not recommended, use webmmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_wav: FFmpeg WAV format muxer (not recommended, use wavenc instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_voc: FFmpeg Creative Voice file format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_rcv: FFmpeg VC-1 test bitstream muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_3gp: FFmpeg 3GP format muxer (not recommended, use gppmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_3g2: FFmpeg 3GP2 format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_swf: FFmpeg Flash format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_spdif: FFmpeg IEC958 - S/PDIF (IEC-61937) muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_sox: FFmpeg SoX native format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_rtsp: FFmpeg RTSP output format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_rm: FFmpeg RealMedia format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_psp: FFmpeg PSP MP4 format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_ogg: FFmpeg Ogg muxer (not recommended, use oggmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_nut: FFmpeg NUT format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mxf_d10: FFmpeg Material eXchange Format, D-10 Mapping muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mxf: FFmpeg Material eXchange Format muxer (not recommended, use mxfmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mpjpeg: FFmpeg MIME multipart JPEG format muxer (not recommended, use multipartmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mpegts: FFmpeg MPEG-2 transport stream format muxer (not recommended, use mpegtsmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_vob: FFmpeg MPEG-2 PS format (VOB) muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_svcd: FFmpeg MPEG-2 PS format (VOB) muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_dvd: FFmpeg MPEG-2 PS format (DVD VOB) muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_vcd: FFmpeg MPEG-1 System format (VCD) muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mpeg: FFmpeg MPEG-1 System format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mp4: FFmpeg MP4 format muxer (not recommended, use mp4mux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mp3: FFmpeg MPEG audio layer 3 formatter (not recommended, use id3v2mux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mp2: FFmpeg MPEG audio layer 2 formatter (not recommended, use id3v2mux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mov: FFmpeg MOV format muxer (not recommended, use qtmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_mmf: FFmpeg Yamaha SMAF muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_matroska: FFmpeg Matroska file format muxer (not recommended, use matroskamux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_ipod: FFmpeg iPod H.264 MP4 format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_gxf: FFmpeg GXF format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_flv: FFmpeg FLV format muxer (not recommended, use flvmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_filmstrip: FFmpeg Adobe Filmstrip muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_ffm: FFmpeg FFM (FFserver live feed) format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_dv: FFmpeg DV video format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_daud: FFmpeg D-Cinema audio format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_avm2: FFmpeg Flash 9 (AVM2) format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_avi: FFmpeg AVI format muxer (not recommended, use avimux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_au: FFmpeg SUN AU format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_asf_stream: FFmpeg ASF format muxer (not recommended, use asfmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_asf: FFmpeg ASF format muxer (not recommended, use asfmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_amr: FFmpeg 3GPP AMR file format muxer
ffmpeg:  ffmux_aiff: FFmpeg Audio IFF muxer (not recommended, use aiffmux instead)
ffmpeg:  ffmux_adts: FFmpeg ADTS AAC muxer (not recommended, use aacparse instead)
ffmpeg: fftype_yuv4mpegpipe: y4m
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_yuv4mpegpipe: FFmpeg YUV4MPEG pipe format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_yop: yop
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_yop: FFmpeg Psygnosis YOP Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_xa: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_xa: FFmpeg Maxis XA File Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_wsvqa: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_wsvqa: FFmpeg Westwood Studios VQA format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_wsaud: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_wsaud: FFmpeg Westwood Studios audio format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_wc3movie: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_wc3movie: FFmpeg Wing Commander III movie format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_wav: FFmpeg WAV format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_w64: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_w64: FFmpeg Sony Wave64 format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_vqf: vqf
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_vqf: FFmpeg Nippon Telegraph and Telephone Corporation (NTT) TwinVQ demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_voc: FFmpeg Creative Voice file format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_vmd: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_vmd: FFmpeg Sierra VMD format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_vc1test: FFmpeg VC-1 test bitstream format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_txd: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_txd: FFmpeg Renderware TeXture Dictionary demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_tta: FFmpeg True Audio demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_tmv: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_tmv: FFmpeg 8088flex TMV demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_tiertexseq: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_tiertexseq: FFmpeg Tiertex Limited SEQ format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_thp: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_thp: FFmpeg THP demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_swf: FFmpeg Flash format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_psxstr: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_psxstr: FFmpeg Sony Playstation STR format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_sox: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_sox: FFmpeg SoX native format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_sol: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_sol: FFmpeg Sierra SOL format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_smk: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_smk: FFmpeg Smacker video demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_siff: vb,son
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_siff: FFmpeg Beam Software SIFF demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_film_cpk: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_film_cpk: FFmpeg Sega FILM/CPK format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_rpl: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_rpl: FFmpeg RPL/ARMovie format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_RoQ: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_RoQ: FFmpeg id RoQ format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_rm: FFmpeg RealMedia format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_rl2: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_rl2: FFmpeg RL2 format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_r3d: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_r3d: FFmpeg REDCODE R3D format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_qcp: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_qcp: FFmpeg QCP format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_pva: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_pva: FFmpeg TechnoTrend PVA file and stream format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_oma: oma,aa3
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_oma: FFmpeg Sony OpenMG audio demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ogg: FFmpeg Ogg demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_nuv: FFmpeg NuppelVideo format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_nut: nut
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_nut: FFmpeg NUT format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_nsv: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_nsv: FFmpeg Nullsoft Streaming Video demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_nc: v
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_nc: FFmpeg NC camera feed format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mxf: FFmpeg Material eXchange Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_mvi: mvi
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mvi: FFmpeg Motion Pixels MVI format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_MTV: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_MTV: FFmpeg MTV format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_msnwctcp: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_msnwctcp: FFmpeg MSN TCP Webcam stream demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mpegtsraw: FFmpeg MPEG-2 raw transport stream format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mpegts: FFmpeg MPEG-2 transport stream format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mpeg: FFmpeg MPEG-PS format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mpc8: FFmpeg Musepack SV8 demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mpc: FFmpeg Musepack demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mp3: FFmpeg MPEG audio layer 2/3 demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mov_mp4_m4a_3gp_3g2_mj2: FFmpeg QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_mmf: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mmf: FFmpeg Yamaha SMAF demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_mm: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_mm: FFmpeg American Laser Games MM format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_matroska: FFmpeg Matroska file format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_lmlm4: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_lmlm4: FFmpeg lmlm4 raw format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_iv8: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_iv8: FFmpeg A format generated by IndigoVision 8000 video server demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_ISS: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ISS: FFmpeg Funcom ISS format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_ipmovie: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ipmovie: FFmpeg Interplay MVE format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_IFF: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_IFF: FFmpeg IFF format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_idcin: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_idcin: FFmpeg id Cinematic format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_gxf: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_gxf: FFmpeg GXF format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_4xm: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_4xm: FFmpeg 4X Technologies format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_flv: FFmpeg FLV format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_flic: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_flic: FFmpeg FLI/FLC/FLX animation format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_filmstrip: flm
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_filmstrip: FFmpeg Adobe Filmstrip demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_ffm: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ffm: FFmpeg FFM (FFserver live feed) format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_ea_cdata: cdata
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ea_cdata: FFmpeg Electronic Arts cdata demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_ea: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ea: FFmpeg Electronic Arts Multimedia Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_dxa: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_dxa: FFmpeg DXA demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_dv: FFmpeg DV video format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_dsicin: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_dsicin: FFmpeg Delphine Software International CIN format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_daud: 302
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_daud: FFmpeg D-Cinema audio format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_cdg: cdg
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_cdg: FFmpeg CD Graphics Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_caf: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_caf: FFmpeg Apple Core Audio Format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_c93: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_c93: FFmpeg Interplay C93 demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_bink: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_bink: FFmpeg Bink demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_bfi: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_bfi: FFmpeg Brute Force & Ignorance demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_bethsoftvid: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_bethsoftvid: FFmpeg Bethesda Softworks VID format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_avs: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_avs: FFmpeg AVS format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_avi: FFmpeg AVI format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_au: FFmpeg SUN AU format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_asf: FFmpeg ASF format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_ape: FFmpeg Monkey's Audio demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_apc: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_apc: FFmpeg CRYO APC format demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_anm: no extensions
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_anm: FFmpeg Deluxe Paint Animation demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_amr: FFmpeg 3GPP AMR file format demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_aiff: FFmpeg Audio IFF demuxer
ffmpeg: fftype_aea: aea
ffmpeg:  ffdemux_aea: FFmpeg MD STUDIO audio demuxer
ffmpeg:  ffdec_xsub: FFmpeg XSUB decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pgssub: FFmpeg HDMV Presentation Graphic Stream subtitles decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dvdsub: FFmpeg DVD subtitles decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dvbsub: FFmpeg DVB subtitles decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_yamaha: FFmpeg ADPCM Yamaha decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_xa: FFmpeg ADPCM CDROM XA decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_thp: FFmpeg ADPCM Nintendo Gamecube THP decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_swf: FFmpeg ADPCM Shockwave Flash decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_sbpro_4: FFmpeg ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 4-bit decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_sbpro_3: FFmpeg ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2.6-bit decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_sbpro_2: FFmpeg ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2-bit decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ms: FFmpeg ADPCM Microsoft decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_ws: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Westwood decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_wav: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA WAV decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_smjpeg: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Loki SDL MJPEG decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_qt: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA QuickTime decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_iss: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Funcom ISS decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_ea_sead: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts SEAD decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_ea_eacs: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts EACS decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_dk4: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Duck DK4 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_dk3: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA Duck DK3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ima_amv: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA AMV decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_g726: FFmpeg G.726 ADPCM decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea_xas: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts XAS decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea_r3: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts R3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea_r2: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts R2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea_r1: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts R1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea_maxis_xa: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts Maxis CDROM XA decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ea: FFmpeg ADPCM Electronic Arts decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_ct: FFmpeg ADPCM Creative Technology decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_adx: FFmpeg SEGA CRI ADX ADPCM decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_adpcm_4xm: FFmpeg ADPCM 4X Movie decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_xan_dpcm: FFmpeg DPCM Xan decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sol_dpcm: FFmpeg DPCM Sol decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_roq_dpcm: FFmpeg DPCM id RoQ decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_interplay_dpcm: FFmpeg DPCM Interplay decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ws_snd1: FFmpeg Westwood Audio (SND1) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmavoice: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio Voice decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmav2: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmav1: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio 1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmapro: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio 9 Professional decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vmdaudio: FFmpeg Sierra VMD audio decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_twinvq: FFmpeg VQF TwinVQ decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_tta: FFmpeg True Audio (TTA) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_truespeech: FFmpeg DSP Group TrueSpeech decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_truehd: FFmpeg TrueHD decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sonic: FFmpeg Sonic decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_smackaud: FFmpeg Smacker audio decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sipr: FFmpeg RealAudio SIPR / ACELP.NET decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_shorten: FFmpeg Shorten decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_real_288: FFmpeg RealAudio 2.0 (28.8K) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_real_144: FFmpeg RealAudio 1.0 (14.4K) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_qdm2: FFmpeg QDesign Music Codec 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_qcelp: FFmpeg QCELP / PureVoice decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_nellymoser: FFmpeg Nellymoser Asao decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mpc8: FFmpeg Musepack SV8 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mpc7: FFmpeg Musepack SV7 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mp3on4: FFmpeg MP3onMP4 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mp3adu: FFmpeg ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mp3: FFmpeg MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mlp: FFmpeg MLP (Meridian Lossless Packing) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mace6: FFmpeg MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 6:1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mace3: FFmpeg MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 3:1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_imc: FFmpeg IMC (Intel Music Coder) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_flac: FFmpeg FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eac3: FFmpeg ATSC A/52B (AC-3, E-AC-3) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dsicinaudio: FFmpeg Delphine Software International CIN audio decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dca: FFmpeg DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cook: FFmpeg COOK decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_binkaudio_rdft: FFmpeg Bink Audio (RDFT) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_binkaudio_dct: FFmpeg Bink Audio (DCT) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_atrac3: FFmpeg Atrac 3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_atrac1: FFmpeg Atrac 1 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ape: FFmpeg Monkey's Audio decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_amrnb: FFmpeg Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_als: FFmpeg MPEG-4 Audio Lossless Coding (ALS) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_alac: FFmpeg ALAC (Apple Lossless Audio Codec) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ac3: FFmpeg ATSC A/52A (AC-3) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_aac: FFmpeg Advanced Audio Coding decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_zmbv: FFmpeg Zip Motion Blocks Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_zlib: FFmpeg LCL (LossLess Codec Library) ZLIB decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_yop: FFmpeg Psygnosis YOP Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_xl: FFmpeg Miro VideoXL decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_xan_wc3: FFmpeg Wing Commander III / Xan decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wnv1: FFmpeg Winnov WNV1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmv3: FFmpeg Windows Media Video 9 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmv2: FFmpeg Windows Media Video 8 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_wmv1: FFmpeg Windows Media Video 7 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vqavideo: FFmpeg Westwood Studios VQA (Vector Quantized Animation) video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vp6f: FFmpeg On2 VP6 (Flash version) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vp6a: FFmpeg On2 VP6 (Flash version, with alpha channel) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vp6: FFmpeg On2 VP6 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vp5: FFmpeg On2 VP5 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vp3: FFmpeg On2 VP3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vmnc: FFmpeg VMware Screen Codec / VMware Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vmdvideo: FFmpeg Sierra VMD video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vcr1: FFmpeg ATI VCR1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vc1: FFmpeg SMPTE VC-1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_vb: FFmpeg Beam Software VB decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ultimotion: FFmpeg IBM UltiMotion decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_txd: FFmpeg Renderware TXD (TeXture Dictionary) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_camtasia: FFmpeg TechSmith Screen Capture Codec decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_truemotion2: FFmpeg Duck TrueMotion 2.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_truemotion1: FFmpeg Duck TrueMotion 1.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_tmv: FFmpeg 8088flex TMV decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_tiff: FFmpeg TIFF image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_tiertexseqvideo: FFmpeg Tiertex Limited SEQ video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_thp: FFmpeg Nintendo Gamecube THP video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_targa: FFmpeg Truevision Targa image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_svq3: FFmpeg Sorenson Vector Quantizer 3 / Sorenson Video 3 / SVQ3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_svq1: FFmpeg Sorenson Vector Quantizer 1 / Sorenson Video 1 / SVQ1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sunrast: FFmpeg Sun Rasterfile image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sp5x: FFmpeg Sunplus JPEG (SP5X) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_snow: FFmpeg Snow decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_smc: FFmpeg QuickTime Graphics (SMC) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_smackvid: FFmpeg Smacker video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_sgi: FFmpeg SGI image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rv40: FFmpeg RealVideo 4.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rv30: FFmpeg RealVideo 3.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rv20: FFmpeg RealVideo 2.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rv10: FFmpeg RealVideo 1.0 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rpza: FFmpeg QuickTime video (RPZA) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_roqvideo: FFmpeg id RoQ video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_rl2: FFmpeg RL2 video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_qtrle: FFmpeg QuickTime Animation (RLE) video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_qpeg: FFmpeg Q-team QPEG decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_qdraw: FFmpeg Apple QuickDraw decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ptx: FFmpeg V.Flash PTX image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ppm: FFmpeg PPM (Portable PixelMap) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_png: FFmpeg PNG image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pgmyuv: FFmpeg PGMYUV (Portable GrayMap YUV) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pgm: FFmpeg PGM (Portable GrayMap) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pcx: FFmpeg PC Paintbrush PCX image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pbm: FFmpeg PBM (Portable BitMap) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_pam: FFmpeg PAM (Portable AnyMap) image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_nuv: FFmpeg NuppelVideo/RTJPEG decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mszh: FFmpeg LCL (LossLess Codec Library) MSZH decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_msvideo1: FFmpeg Microsoft Video 1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_msrle: FFmpeg Microsoft RLE decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_msmpeg4: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_msmpeg4v2: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_msmpeg4v1: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mpegvideo: FFmpeg MPEG-1 video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mpeg4: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mpeg2video: FFmpeg MPEG-2 video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_motionpixels: FFmpeg Motion Pixels video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mmvideo: FFmpeg American Laser Games MM Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mjpegb: FFmpeg Apple MJPEG-B decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mjpeg: FFmpeg MJPEG (Motion JPEG) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mimic: FFmpeg Mimic decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_mdec: FFmpeg Sony PlayStation MDEC (Motion DECoder) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_loco: FFmpeg LOCO decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_kmvc: FFmpeg Karl Morton's video codec decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_kgv1: FFmpeg Kega Game Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_jpegls: FFmpeg JPEG-LS decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_interplayvideo: FFmpeg Interplay MVE video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_indeo5: FFmpeg Intel Indeo Video Interactive 5 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_indeo3: FFmpeg Intel Indeo 3 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_indeo2: FFmpeg Intel Indeo 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_iff_ilbm: FFmpeg IFF ILBM decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_iff_byterun1: FFmpeg IFF ByteRun1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_idcinvideo: FFmpeg id Quake II CIN video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_huffyuv: FFmpeg Huffyuv / HuffYUV decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_h264: FFmpeg H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_h263i: FFmpeg Intel H.263 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_h263: FFmpeg H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_h261: FFmpeg H.261 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_FRWU: FFmpeg Forward Uncompressed decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_fraps: FFmpeg Fraps decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_4xm: FFmpeg 4X Movie decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_flv: FFmpeg Flash Video (FLV) / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_flic: FFmpeg Autodesk Animator Flic video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_flashsv: FFmpeg Flash Screen Video v1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ffvhuff: FFmpeg Huffyuv FFmpeg variant decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_ffv1: FFmpeg FFmpeg video codec #1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_escape124: FFmpeg Escape 124 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_8svx_fib: FFmpeg 8SVX fibonacci decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_8svx_exp: FFmpeg 8SVX exponential decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_8bps: FFmpeg QuickTime 8BPS video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eatqi: FFmpeg Electronic Arts TQI Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eatgv: FFmpeg Electronic Arts TGV video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eatgq: FFmpeg Electronic Arts TGQ video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eamad: FFmpeg Electronic Arts Madcow Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_eacmv: FFmpeg Electronic Arts CMV video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dxa: FFmpeg Feeble Files/ScummVM DXA decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dvvideo: FFmpeg DV (Digital Video) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dsicinvideo: FFmpeg Delphine Software International CIN video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dpx: FFmpeg DPX image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_dnxhd: FFmpeg VC3/DNxHD decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cyuv: FFmpeg Creative YUV (CYUV) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_camstudio: FFmpeg CamStudio decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cljr: FFmpeg Cirrus Logic AccuPak decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cinepak: FFmpeg Cinepak decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cdgraphics: FFmpeg CD Graphics video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_cavs: FFmpeg Chinese AVS video (AVS1-P2, JiZhun profile) decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_c93: FFmpeg Interplay C93 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_bmp: FFmpeg BMP image decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_binkvideo: FFmpeg Bink video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_bfi: FFmpeg Brute Force & Ignorance decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_bethsoftvid: FFmpeg Bethesda VID video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_avs: FFmpeg AVS (Audio Video Standard) video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_aura2: FFmpeg Auravision Aura 2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_aura: FFmpeg Auravision AURA decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_asv2: FFmpeg ASUS V2 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_asv1: FFmpeg ASUS V1 decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_anm: FFmpeg Deluxe Paint Animation decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_amv: FFmpeg AMV Video decoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_aasc: FFmpeg Autodesk RLE decoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_xsub: FFmpeg DivX subtitles (XSUB) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_dvdsub: FFmpeg DVD subtitles encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_dvbsub: FFmpeg DVB subtitles encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_yamaha: FFmpeg ADPCM Yamaha encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_swf: FFmpeg ADPCM Shockwave Flash encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_ms: FFmpeg ADPCM Microsoft encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_ima_wav: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA WAV encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_ima_qt: FFmpeg ADPCM IMA QuickTime encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_g726: FFmpeg G.726 ADPCM encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_adpcm_adx: FFmpeg SEGA CRI ADX ADPCM encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_roq_dpcm: FFmpeg id RoQ DPCM encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_wmav2: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio 2 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_wmav1: FFmpeg Windows Media Audio 1 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_sonicls: FFmpeg Sonic lossless encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_sonic: FFmpeg Sonic encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_nellymoser: FFmpeg Nellymoser Asao encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_mp2: FFmpeg MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_alac: FFmpeg ALAC (Apple Lossless Audio Codec) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_ac3: FFmpeg ATSC A/52A (AC-3) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_aac: FFmpeg Advanced Audio Coding encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_zmbv: FFmpeg Zip Motion Blocks Video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_wmv2: FFmpeg Windows Media Video 8 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_wmv1: FFmpeg Windows Media Video 7 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_tiff: FFmpeg TIFF image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_targa: FFmpeg Truevision Targa image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_svq1: FFmpeg Sorenson Vector Quantizer 1 / Sorenson Video 1 / SVQ1 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_snow: FFmpeg Snow encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_sgi: FFmpeg SGI image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_rv20: FFmpeg RealVideo 2.0 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_rv10: FFmpeg RealVideo 1.0 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_roqvideo: FFmpeg id RoQ video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_qtrle: FFmpeg QuickTime Animation (RLE) video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_ppm: FFmpeg PPM (Portable PixelMap) image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_png: FFmpeg PNG image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_pgmyuv: FFmpeg PGMYUV (Portable GrayMap YUV) image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_pgm: FFmpeg PGM (Portable GrayMap) image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_pcx: FFmpeg PC Paintbrush PCX image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_pbm: FFmpeg PBM (Portable BitMap) image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_pam: FFmpeg PAM (Portable AnyMap) image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_msmpeg4: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_msmpeg4v2: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_msmpeg4v1: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_mpeg4: FFmpeg MPEG-4 part 2 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_mpeg2video: FFmpeg MPEG-2 video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_mpeg1video: FFmpeg MPEG-1 video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_mjpeg: FFmpeg MJPEG (Motion JPEG) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_ljpeg: FFmpeg Lossless JPEG encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_jpegls: FFmpeg JPEG-LS encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_huffyuv: FFmpeg Huffyuv / HuffYUV encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_h263p: FFmpeg H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_h263: FFmpeg H.263 / H.263-1996 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_h261: FFmpeg H.261 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_flv: FFmpeg Flash Video (FLV) / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_flashsv: FFmpeg Flash Screen Video encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_ffvhuff: FFmpeg Huffyuv FFmpeg variant encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_ffv1: FFmpeg FFmpeg video codec #1 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_dvvideo: FFmpeg DV (Digital Video) encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_dnxhd: FFmpeg VC3/DNxHD encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_bmp: FFmpeg BMP image encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_asv2: FFmpeg ASUS V2 encoder
ffmpeg:  ffenc_asv1: FFmpeg ASUS V1 encoder
postproc:  postproc_ffmpegdeint: LibPostProc ffmpegdeint filter
ffmpegcolorspace:  ffmpegcolorspace: FFMPEG Colorspace converter
```

Comment: Please formulate a single question that is possible to answer.

Comment: No Archlinux package provides the file "gst-inspect". Where did you get it? Is your system possible not up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 0.10.12-1` provides both an en- and decoder for G722:

```
$ gst-inspect-0.10 | grep 722
ffmpeg:  ffenc_g722: FFmpeg G.722 ADPCM encoder
ffmpeg:  ffdec_g722: FFmpeg G.722 ADPCM decoder
rtp:  rtpg722depay: RTP audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpg722pay: RTP audio payloader
```